# error: invalid types ‘const bool[int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays, types, subscript

Is anybody there who can help me please?
I don't know what i have to change. I want to create a 2D grid and some other things.

Here's the most important part of my code.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

bool cells;
const MAX_GRID_SIZE;

//_________________________________________________
void initializeGame() {
  initscr();
  cbreak();
  noecho();
  curs_set(false);
  nodelay(stdscr, true);
  keypad(stdscr, true);
  mousemask(ALL_MOUSE_EVENTS, NULL);

  // Cells (0 = false, 1 = true).
  MAX_GRID_SIZE = 500
  cells[MAX_GRID_SIZE][MAX_GRID_SIZE] = { 0 };
}
//_________________________________________________
void showState() {
  while (true) {
    MEVENT event;
    int key = getch();
    if (key == KEY_MOUSE) {
      if (getmouse(&event) == OK && (event.bstate & BUTTON1_CLICKED)) {
        int x = event.x;
        int y = event.y;
        mvprintw(0, 0, "Mouse clicked at %d, %d\n", x, y);
        cells[x][y] = !cells[x][y];
        if (cells[x][y] == true) { attron(A_REVERSE); }
        mvprintw(y, x, " ");
        attroff(A_REVERSE);
        refresh();
      }
    }
  }

  // Clean up.
  endwin();
}
```

Comment: Your variable has the type `const bool cells;` yet you are trying to access it like a 2D array `cells[500][500]`?

Comment: `const bool cells;` is not an array. If it was though, why would you make it const when you want to change the contents?

Comment: okay, i edited my code, but there is still the same error

Comment: @Arenosa "_okay, i edited my code, but there is still the same error_" Sure you edited the code.. But the reason is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `cells` is meant to be a 2D array then declare it as such:

```
const size_t MAX_GRID_SIZE = 500;
bool cells[MAX_GRID_SIZE][MAX_GRID_SIZE] = { 0 };
```